# Cannot update object in an AfterInsert Trigger due to an authorization exception

Tags: trigger, opportunity, authorization, zuora

Following is the error that I'm receiving.

```
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:zuoraSubscriptionTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id ###############;
first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You are not authorized to change the value in this field.
Please contact Sales Operations.: [Zuora_Subscription__c]

Class.zuoraSubscriptionTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert: line 52, column 1
Trigger.zuoraSubscriptionTrigger: line 10, column 1
```

Following is the problematic piece of code from the `zuoraSubscriptionTriggerHandler` class.

```
public static void handleAfterInsert(Map<Id, Zuora__Subscription__c> newMap) {
    If((mapOfSwitch != NULL && mapOfSwitch.containsKey('ChurnedCustomer') 
    && mapOfSwitch.get('ChurnedCustomer').isActive__c) || test.isRunningTest()){
        churnedCustomer(newMap,null,true);
    }
    Set<String> externalIds = new Set<String>();
    for(Zuora__Subscription__c s : newMap.values()) {
        if(s.Name != '' && s.Name != null) {
            externalIds.add(s.Name);
        }
    }
    List<opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>([select id, Zuora_Subscription_ID__c, Zuora_Subscription__c from opportunity where Zuora_Subscription_ID__c in :externalIds]);
    List<opportunity> toUpdate = new List<opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity o : opps) {
        for(Zuora__Subscription__c s : newMap.values()) {
            if(o.Zuora_Subscription_ID__c == s.Name && o.Zuora_Subscription__c != s.id) {
                o.Zuora_Subscription__c = s.id;
                toUpdate.add(o);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(!toUpdate.isEmpty())
        update toUpdate;  // This is at line #52
}
```

From what I understand, the user being used to make the update doesn't have access to the `Zuora_Subscription__c` field in the `Opportunity` object which is a Lookup field to the Zuora Subscription object. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

I checked and the user has both read and edit access to the above field. Please refer to the following screenshot. It shows the Object setting for Opportunities for the concerned profile.

[image: Object setting for Opportunities for the concerned profile]

Please provide some suggestions as to how I can figure out the actual issue.

Comment: There is a validation rule configured on the `Zuora__Subscription__c` object. Look at the criteria for this rule and you will know why the User is being blocked from the change.

Comment: @TSmith - There aren't any validation rules on the Zuora Subscription object

Comment: Your error message is telling us, explicitly, that you are failing on a custom validation rule. If you don't have any validation rules on your Zuora Subscription object, then the update of this object is triggering other workflow that does have a validation rule. Until you find the validation rule this error will continue.

Comment: @PapaChaos - There is a Validation Rule on the Opportunity object that seems to be the one causing the issue. Thanks for the help. Looks like I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: @TSmith - you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a validation rule configured on the `Zuora__Subscription__c` object. Look at the criteria for this rule and you will know why the User is being blocked from the change.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/342984/30493) may help you with understanding why you might see a validation exception that is configured on a different object than the modified record.